# Kudan iOS project made with Unity shows only Green Screen

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, xcode8, kudan, il2cpp

I am trying to build a Kudan project that uses the SLAM technology by following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Olkf0rxmgk0. I have done so, but when I build for iOS and run (in XCode8) I get only a green screen and a square in the corner saying "Tracker not Running." Furthermore, the console throws the following errors:

> (Filename: currently not available on il2cpp Line: -1)
>
> [KudanAR] Failed to create external textures
>   Kudan.AR.TrackeriOS:UpdateBackground()
>   Kudan.AR.TrackeriOS:UpdateTracking() Kudan.AR.KudanTracker:Update()
>   (Filename:
>   /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/artifacts/generated/common/runtime/UnityEngineDebugBindings.gen.cpp
>   Line: 42)
>
> NullReferenceException: A null value was found where an object
>   instance was required.   at Kudan.AR.KudanTracker.Update () [0x00000]
>   in :0

By the way, because I was getting compiler errors, I had to disable Bitcode from the project's settings.

Does anybody have an idea of why this might be happening?